# How can I know if I'm suffering data loss during Kafka Connect intermittent read-from-source issues?

Tags: apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are running Kafka Connect using the [Confluent JDBC Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html) to read from a [DB2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Db2_Family) database. Periodically, we see issues like this in our Kafka Connect logs:

```
kafkaconnect-deploy-prod-967ddfffb-5l4cm 2021-04-23 10:39:43.770 ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="PRODSCHEMA"."VW_PRODVIEW", query='null', topicPrefix='some-topic-prefix-', incrementingColumn='', timestampColumns=[UPDATEDATETIME]}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:404)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007, SQLERRMC=1;PRODSCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE, DRIVER=4.28.11
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:815)
    ...
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k7.bd(k7.java:785)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k7.executeQuery(k7.java:750)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:200)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:159)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:371)
```

This appears to be an intermittent issue connecting to DB2, and is semi-expected; for reasons outside the scope of this question, we know that the network between the two is unreliable.

However, what we are trying to establish is whether in this circumstance data loss is likely to have occurred. I've found [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/) which talks about error handling in Kafka Connect, but it only refers to errors due to broken messages, not the actual connectivity between Kafka Connect and the data source.

In this case, how would we know if the failure to connect had caused data loss? (i.e. records in our data source that were not processed for target topic). Would there be errors in the Kafka Connect log? Will Kafka Connect always retry indefinitely when it has a connectivity issue? Are there any controls over its retry?

(If it matters, Kafka Connect is version 2.5; it is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster, in distributed mode, but with only one actual running worker/container.)

Comment: The specific exception SQL0668N reason code 1 is a temporary condition on the source table in Db2. This is not a connection error or connectivity error , and it is not a network error. No data will be returned (to kafka connect) until the source table has been returned to a normal state (either by a programmed action , or manual action ).  The answer to your question re data loss will depend on how you identify deltas in the source table, upon retry.

Comment: @mao thanks for the clarity, I didn't know that. I think the question re: Kafka Connect still remains (it's the KC connector making the determination), but useful to know that's not a connection issue.

Comment: @mao incidentally, this page seems to cover off the DB2 issue fairly well: https://datageek.blog/en/2015/12/15/db2-load-utility-and-check-pending-states/.